# Essential Image of the Étale Homotopy type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, etale-cohomology, etale-covers

For any scheme $X$ we can associate the étale homotopy type $Et(X)$, which is a pro-object in the homotopy category of CW-complexes. My question is, do we have a good understanding of the essential image, i.e., do we have a set of necessary and sufficient conditions on a pro-CW-complex for it to be the étale homotopy type of some scheme. Even more "ambitiously", do we have such a set of conditions such that a pro-CW-complex is the étale homotopy type of a smooth projective scheme $K$-scheme?

Comment: I am not sure if one of these tasks is more ambitious than the other. It seems unlikely that you could characterize all the possible fundamental groups for smooth projective $\mathbb{C}$-schemes. By the way what is $K$ in your question? Depending on whether it is separably closed or not we are dealing with rather different problems).

Comment: What is your construction of the homotopy type for non-locally Noetherian schemes?

Comment: @vrz The étale homotopy type is perfectly well defined for any scheme, by taking the [shape](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shape+of+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos) of the étale topos, although probably considering only the profinite shape would make the question more approachable.

Comment: @vrz I'm happy to assume that $K$ is spearably closed and characteristic zero, if that helps in any way.